# Setting up proxy in Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, webserver

What is proxy ?

Why do we need proxy and for what purpose ?

I am new to server. When i was installing ubuntu server. Installation prompt is asking me for a proxy information **"h ttp://[[user][:pass]@]host[:port]/"**. Now what should i do.

Comment: I guess you should begin by checking Wikipedia to begin with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server , as your question is not really specific!

Comment: As it stands, this question is off topic. Please [edit] it to include more details as to what you are asking.

Comment: @alci i didnt get usefull information to get started.

Comment: Tim I am new to server. When i was installing ubuntu server. installation prompt is asking me for a proxy information **"http://[[user][:pass]@]host[:port]/"**. Now what should i do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proxy information is needed in the case when you're on a network that does not allow you to directly access the internet, and mandates you use a special server called a proxy.

As the installer has to retrieve informations from the web, it is giving you a chance to configure the proxy here.

If you are not aware of it (ie you're not on a corporate or university network for example), you most probably don't need it, so just skip this part.